# Reputation transaction history is incomplete (missing today’s paired transactions)

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/518010/how-do-i-create-a-bash-script-that-chooses-the-right-frequency-for-wlan-channel/518047#518047), which I posted 2012–12–11 21:27:14Z, got accepted and unaccepted within the following 26 hours.  The following screen shots were taken 2012–12–12, approximately 16:40Z and 22:40Z:

[image: answer count with checkmark]        
[image: answer count without checkmark]

and my reputation dropped 15 points in that interval.  But my Reputation history display doesn’t show either the accept or the unaccept:

[image: history, not showing accept/unaccept]

Is this normal?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily consider this a bug. If it was unaccepted on the same day, the system might simply not log it. You didn't lose rep because you never got it (on that day). "Unaccept" actions are only shown when they happen later, AFAICT.

Comment: It's probably an intended behavior, similar to the 5 minute grace period for edits. Imagine how repeated vote/unvote clicks (intentional or accidental) would mess up your statistics.